# Bootstrap affix with custom JS and CSS overlapping HTML elements/positioned incorrectly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/

On the following website I am using the Bootstrap affix component applied to a div with the class of `.bcit-sidebar` however I have encountered an issue.

I am trying to dynamically position `.bcit-sidebar` with the classes inside of a media query. When the user scrolls the `top: 80px;` property ensures the sidebar follows the user.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .bcit-sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
  }
  .bcit-sidebar.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute; 
  }
}
```

I have applied the following script to ensure `.bcit-sidebar` is positioned correctly:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var $sideBar = $('.bcit-sidebar')

  $sideBar.affix({
    offset: {
      top: function () {
        var offsetTop      = $sideBar.offset().top
        var sideBarMargin  = parseInt($sideBar.children(0).css('margin-top'), 10)
        var navOuterHeight = $('.bcit-nav').height()

        return (this.top = offsetTop - navOuterHeight - sideBarMargin)
      }
    , bottom: function () {
        return (this.bottom = $('.bcit-footer').outerHeight(true))
      }
    }
  })
}, 100)
```

However the sidebar is overlapping the orange page header called `.bcit-heading` if the user begins to scroll - which I do not want to occur. I have tried increasing the value of  `top: 80px;` set on `.bcit-sidebar.affix` to `top: 180px;`, and this eliminates the issue shown here:

[image]

But this in turn introduces a new issue - the sidebar no longer aligns with the corresponding height of the `.page-headers`. These elements should horizontally align but maybe it *isn't* possible to achieve the sidebar not overlapping the orange header while still horizontally aligning with the page headers . Any ideas on how to resolve this issue by amending the CSS/JavaScript?

I want to match the behavior of affix on the Bootstrap docs (They seem to have achieved it somehow) - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to override the bootstrap behaviour like this...

```
.bcit-sidebar {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

Not very nice, but it seems to work. I recommend adding an additional class to make sure you don't get unexpected behaviour somewhere else. For example add a class disable-scrolling...

```
.bcit-sidebar.disable-scrolling {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to amend my JavaScript running when the DOM loads to a fixed value of 399. This was the estimate height of all the elements above.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var $sideBar = $('.bcit-sidebar')

  $sideBar.affix({
    offset: {
      top: 399
    , bottom: function () {
        return (this.bottom = $('.bcit-footer').outerHeight(true))
      }
    }
  })
}, 100)
```